# Can a.NET variable length params method be called from Managed C++?

Tags: c#, parameters, managed-c++

I have a method declared on an interface like so:

```
public interface IInterface
{
    void DoSomething(string format, params object[] arguments);
}
```

I am dynamically loading a managed c++ class that uses an implementation of this interface. The interface and inmplementation are both C#.

```
IInterface^ foo = gcnew Implentation();
```

This call is fine:

```
foo->DoSomething("string", someParam);
```

This call fails:

```
foo->DoSomething("string");
```

It looks like if there are no parameters to pass it just can't resolve the method which should accept *any* number of params (including zero of course). I could probably use a nullptr as a placeholder but that's pretty ugly or I could add a superfluous overload of `DoSomething(string format)` which isn't great either but better than making all calls more awkward than they should be.

Am I missing something or is this not supported? All the helpers on the internet show how to declare the params equivalent in c++ but that doesn't help in my scenario.

Comment: Just to be clear, is the C++ class implementing the interface, or using a class that implements it? The text says that it's using another class, but the `IInterface foo = new Implementation();` is C# code.

Comment: I've updated the question to be clearer. The c++ class owns an instance of a C# class (which implements a C# interface).

Comment: Ugh, sorry. Yes of course it should be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't replicate your problem.

Given the C# interface & implementation:

```
using System;

namespace SomeNamespace
{
    public interface IInterface
    {
        void Print(string format, params object[] args);
    }

    public class Implementation : IInterface
    {
        public void Print(string format, params object[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(format, args);
        }
    }
}
```

This C++/CLI code works fine:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace SomeNamespace;

public ref class Test
{
public:
    static void Run()
    {
        IInterface^ foo = gcnew Implementation();
        foo->Print("hello, {0}", "world");
        foo->Print("hello, world");
    }
};
```

Is there another element that is missing here? Or have I missed the point :)

Comment: No, I believe you've got it :) That's exactly the behavior I would have expected but when I try either of my suggestions (nullptr or overloads) everything works fine. The only thing I didn't mention is that the c++ class is being loaded dynamically via reflection but this is working with no problems in other cases. It's been a long time since I've touched c++ at all so in the managed world it's much more likely that _I've_ missed something (compiler options or somesuch).